# Batch file to move contents of a folder with Subfolders to same structure on Partition drive

Tags: batch-file

I am wondering how to create a .bat file to move all files within a folder containing subfolders to an identical setup on a different volume.

For example, Folder called Support with Subfolders called Support1, Support2 etc. I want to move files greater than 5 days and update the existing files in the partition drive.

```
Support 
    -> Support1 -> Contains files
    -> Support2 -> Contains files
```

Comment: ventsyv's answer is correct in that we **guess** that this is on windows. If not check out rsync and or find (find has timestamp capabilities).

Also, do you want explicitly a .bat file or will .cmd or .ps do. (powershell is probably the way to go here. But as asked it is not a valid answer give a powershell script).

Comment: I want to run it as a scheduled task and a .bat file was the easiest.

Comment: I am most grateful if this could be answered. and yes older than 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about a batch file, I'll assume this is on Windows

```
xcopy /E /T /D:m-d-y <top level source dir> <destination>
```

/D:m-d-y will copy only files changed on or after the specified date.

Comment: A good start. Now the >5 days part.

Comment: Duh, somehow I glossed over that...

Comment: He want's to copy files **older** than 5 days not **newer**

Comment: Duh, maybe the third times' the charm...